# Create Stream on startup/by script

Tags: spring-xd

I'm looking to create a stream on startup of spring-xd container without having to manually enter it via xd-shell.  I want to;
1. have xd-singlenode startup (invoked via bash)
2. have a pre-created stream definition (e.g. `http --port=8080 | file`) deployed after the container starts up

I know there's a url to invoke (`curl -POST http://127.0.0.1:9393/streams?name=mystream&definition=http|file`) but I'm having troubles with specifying additional configuration (like `--port=8080`) and the pipe (`|`) is causing some troubles too.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the answer is that you can pass arguments (stream configurations) as a command line argument

```
xd-shell --cmdFile [filename]
```

The contents of the command file are what you would enter via the shell so where you would do this

```
xd:>stream create --name teststream --definition "http | file" --deploy
```

you would write a file like this

```
stream create --name teststream --definition "http | file" --deploy
```

so as an example;

```
xd-shell --cmdFile stream.cmd
```

all of which can be invoked from a shell

Comment: Not sure if it changed recently but the argument is actually `--cmdfile` (all lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/src/test/scripts You should find similar examples using curl.

Also note that if you are running with an external ZooKeeper ensemble, which is the operational configuration, you don't need to do this. ZK persists and restores the XD cluster state upon restart so any streams that were deployed at shutdown will be deployed at start up. Single node starts an embedded ZK server by default, but may be configured to connect to an external server. For example,

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dzk.client.connect=localhost:2181
```

zk.client.connect accepts a comma-delimited string of host:port pairs